# unable to see the Application created in the tenant domain inside the service provider section of the carbon management console of the tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have created tenant api.com in the wso2 api manager 3.1.0 . created the application HelloWorldApp in the developer portal of the tenant. But this application is not appearing in the service provider section of the tenant admin. But the corresponding role is created in the roles section. please see the below figure for confirmation[image]

This happens only if the non tenant admin user has created the application. If the tenant admin has created the application then application appears in the service provider section.

I am using wso2 IS-KM as key manager

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour. The applications created by different users in the same tenant domain are visible and accessible only to the particular user. If you want applications to be shared among users, you will have to enable **Application Sharing**. Please refer [1] for more details.

To access the service provider application specific to a particular user from the carbon console, you will have to login with the specific user credentials. For this, you will have to give the admin role to the user and then try to login.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/consume-api/manage-application/sharing-applications/sharing-applications/

Comment: I need to share the application created by the super tenant to other tenants. In service provider section I have enabled the saas flag. But enabling only this flag is not making that application appear in the devportal of the other tenants. How can make this possible?

Comment: Hi user3553913, you cannot share the applications created by one tenant with another tenant. This is not supported. Were you able to try out and see whether Application sharing feature[1] helps to achieve your requirement? [1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/consume-api/manage-application/sharing-applications/sharing-applications/